# Proving ratio of sides of two triangles with congruent corresponding angles

Tags: geometry

How to prove that, if each angle in one triangle is congruent to its corresponding angle in another triangle, then the ratios of their corresponding sides will be equal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is called *similarity* or *an astonishing consequence of Thales' theorem*.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [Sine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), we know that $$\frac{a}{\sin A}  = \frac{b}{\sin B}  = \frac{c}{\sin C}  $$

(where the upper-case letter angle is opposite the lower-case side)

So the sides of any two triangles with congruent angles will have sides in the ratio $\sin A : \sin B : \sin C$

Comment: So simple, very nice.